# How to detect spy software like flexispy, mspy, phonesheriff?

Tags: malware

I don't want to factory reset my phone nor do I want to reflash Lineage OS ROM. I just want to check for a possible trace of spy software like flexispy, mspy, phonesheriff, ikeymonitor thetruthspy, and possibly others that I don't know of.

Just to check for root is enough? I have not installed the root feature of Lineage OS.

Is there any way which could do that? I don't mind doing things manually but I need to know instructions or pointers to begin with.

Comment: I have seen a site suggesting using a wifi access point to sniff network traffic from/to the phone. I could turn my rpi into an AP and sniff traffic but it will be tedious to check for every connection made by the phone to see if it's legit or not. But I could try. I just hoped for something else.

Comment: So the AP idea has limited value because there is encrypted traffic. And all info you have is at best a domain name or worse only an IP that the phone connected to. You could only make limited guesses then...